# Oracle APEX Restrict Shared component LOV during run time

Tags: dynamic, conditional-statements, apex, lov

I have a requirement to show 7 columns in the select list of the LOV, I tried using shared component LOV but unable to restrict it based on the values from the form field.

let's say there is a field :P100_Customer.

My shared component LOV is

SELECT order_number, shipment_date, shipped_qty
FROM table;

When my LOV is parsed i want to restrict it like below
SELECT order_number, shipment_date, shipped_qty
FROM table
WHERE customer = :P100_customer;

Answer (score 0):

You may try `customer = v(‘P’|| :APP_PAGE_ID || ‘_CUSTOMER’ ) Where :APP_PAGE_ID`

it will return the value as `100`